# Why don't switches appear in circuit diagrams of DC motors?

Tags: dc-motor

DC motors are typically represented in circuit diagrams as follows,

[image: DC Motor]

This sort of diagram seems to show up in controls and system dynamics courses.

Most common DC motors have commutators, switches that change the direction of current in the armature coils. Without a commutator, a DC coil would just act like an electromagnet and align with the stator field. With a commutator, the induced magnetic field changes direction, twice per revolution. The faster the rotor turns, the faster the current in the inductor should change direction. This switch never shows up in the textbook diagrams I see. What gives?

Is the inductor in this diagram the actual coils of wire in the armature, or does it represent an effective inductance that is averaged out over time? Also, is back voltage constant at a constant angular velocity, or does it, too, switch on and off? Is all of this a pious lie disseminated by controls professors?

Comment: This only shows Torque in one position.   Commutation can be magnetically sensed and switched electronically or by positions of rotor armature contacts and brushes. Both depend on number of pole pairs. Only 1/2 a pole pair is shown in this simple diagram. The concept is show a rotary solenoid as a 1st idea.

Comment: The detailed structure of components is not appropriate in schematics.

Comment: The diagram seems to lack details, such as commutation and multiple pole pairs. If these details are absent, are they simply unimportant in modeling DC motors, or are the textbook models conceptually flawed?

Answer (score 2):

The main reason that your "switches" are never shown in a principle schematic is of practical nature. There is no need to show all the details for a good understanding of the schematic. If the subject changes to understanding the actual construction of a DC motor or generator and the types of winding involved more details are given.

The inductor in combination with the rotor in your diagram represents a socalled serial DC motor. Here only the principle of the motor is shown and not the actual coils in the armature or stator (L). Depending on the design there could be many coils and brushes. In an electronic equivalent the brushes are replaced with semiconductors.

When an armature turns in a magnetic field (L in your figure) a back voltage is generated. That voltage is in average constant at constant angular velocity of the armature. For each individual winding this is not the situation. In practice the commutator "switches on and off" and changes the action to a different winding. In fact the voltage induced in the winding has a sinus form.

Since there is a fixed field in the drawing this type of motor is a socalled shunt motor. The field has thereby a constant voltage applied although it is possible to make the exitation of the field adjustable to regulate the velocity of the rotor. Less exitation results in a higher speed.

Comment: It's not a serial DC motor. See the "Fixed field" coil on the top right corner?

Comment: @Janka. If the field was there in the past then I have overlooked it. Corrected in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have an improper concept of what a schematic diagram is and what it is used for. The INTERNAL DETAILS of components (like motors or integrated circuits) is NOT shown because it is not important to understanding how everything interconnects and works together.

Certainly, if you want to know the INTERNAL DETAILS of anything from a resistor to an integrated circuit with literally billions of transistors, you can find the documentation. But none of that is important to a schematic diagram.

The textbook models are NOT "conceptually flawed", because they are trying to demonstrate the CONCEPT, not show details of how a brushed DC motor is designed and constructed.  To be sure, there is information about how brushed DC motors work, how they are made and what are the principles of operation and design and construction.

Answer (score 1):

> Most common DC motors have commutators

Which *is* shown in the diagram! The symbol for a brushed DC motor is a crude representation of its commutator and brushes viewed end-on.

[image]

Actually in that circuit the symbol represents a DC *generator*. Since a DC motor *is* a generator when the shaft is rotated mechanically, the same symbol can be used for both. And when the motor is running it is *also* acting as a generator, producing a 'back-emf' voltage which opposes the supply voltage.

> Is the inductor in this diagram the actual coils of wire in the
>   armature

Yes. L is the inductance of the armature windings, and R is the resistance of the windings and brushes. These are shown in series with the generator because voltage induced into the windings is effectively in series with them.

> The faster the rotor turns, the faster the current in the inductor
>   should change direction. This switch never shows up in the textbook
>   diagrams I see. What gives?

In this model it is not considered. The winding inductance is so low that it is presumed to have negligible effect at normal running speed, and the rectifying action of the commutator turns the AC into DC so the changing current direction *inside* the armature is irrelevant.